# JabRef: Technical Paper

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, jabref, paper

I am writing a technical paper right now for a seminar. For citing I am using JabRef and many of my references are also technical papers. How do I correctly maintain the references into JabRef? Is it under the topic "Proceedings", "InProceedings" or "Conference"? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean by "technical paper". `@techreport` comes to mind, though these are usually published by some institution and often have an "ID number". Otherwise `@misc` is the standard fallback.

Comment: `File` > `New biblatex library` (a) > Make a  new empty reference of each type (`@misc`, `@article`, etc.) and try to type you  most complete complex reference of your documents. That with enough/proper fields  for your reference is what you want.  (*) Note that `New bibtex llbrary` will allow only some of these  types).

Comment: Feel free to checko our documentation and raise points of improvement: https://docs.jabref.org/ - I would also recommend "Latex für Geisteswissenschaftler". It is abook published soon: https://github.com/thomas-hilarius-meyer/LaTeX-fuer-Geisteswissenschaftler/blob/gh-pages/lfgw.pdf.

Comment: For German readers, the long manual of JabRef could provide some insights, too? --> https://manuals.jabref.org/JabRef-UserManual_de.pdf